# Not a GROUP BY expression trying to count course participants

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by, count

I'm trying to do a SQL statement which shows me which employees have followed a 
certain course more than once. This is my following SQL:

```
SELECT m.mnr, m.name, count(i.cursist) 
FROM employee m, registrations i
WHERE i.cursist = m.mnr
GROUP BY i.cursist;
```

The MNR is the primary for the employees and CURSIST is the foreign key for this in the registrations table.

It returns the error:

> Not a group by expression Error at Line: 1 Column: 8

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, *never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Second, the unaggregated columns go in the `GROUP BY`.  So:

```
SELECT m.mnr, m.name, count(i.cursist) 
FROM employee m JOIN
     registrations i
     ON i.cursist = m.mnr
GROUP BY m.mnr, m.name;
```

For *more than once*, you want:

```
HAVING COUNT(i.cursist) > 1
```

Comment: add "HAVING count(i.cursist) > 1" after the GROUP BY clause

Comment: Proper? Standard? Aren't , and join equivalent? I mean, I can get that you preffer join for clarity.

Comment: This made me understand group by a bit more again thank you. completely forgot about the unaggregrated columns!

Answer (score 0):

Include `m.mnr, m.name` to `GROUP BY` clause and exclude `i.cursist`

```
SELECT m.mnr, m.name, count(i.cursist) 
FROM employee m inner join 
     registrations i
     on i.cursist = m.mnr
GROUP BY m.mnr, m.name
HAVING count(i.cursist) > 1;
```

I have use explicit `JOIN` syntax instead of old style with commas